# Receiving error "Cannot perform 'ror_' with a dtyped [object] array and scalar of type [bool]" while trying to perform complex query (Pandas)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like:

```
CLIENT | CAMPAING START DATE
CLIENT1| Jul/21
CLIENT2| Aug/21
```

I want to delete some rows with a certain client and certain month.
I wrote:

```
df.loc[~((df['CLIENT'].str.contains('CLIENT1') & (df['CAMPAIGN START DATE']=="Jul/21" | df['CAMPAIGN START DATE']=="Aug/21" | df['CAMPAIGN START DATE']=="Sep/21" | df['CAMPAIGN START DATE']=="Oct/21" | df['CAMPAIGN START DATE']=="Nov/21" | df['CAMPAIGN START DATE']=="Dec/21") ))]
```

I receive this error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot perform 'ror_' with a dtyped [object] array and scalar of type [bool]
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your solution missing `()`, but is possible simplify solution for test membership by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df.loc[~((df['CLIENT'].str.contains('CLIENT1') & ((df['CAMPAIGN START DATE']=="Jul/21") | (df['CAMPAIGN START DATE']=="Aug/21") | (df['CAMPAIGN START DATE']=="Sep/21") | (df['CAMPAIGN START DATE']=="Oct/21" )| (df['CAMPAIGN START DATE']=="Nov/21") | (df['CAMPAIGN START DATE']=="Dec/21")) ))]
```

---

```
df.loc[~(df['CLIENT'].str.contains('CLIENT1') & 
         df['CAMPAIGN START DATE'].isin(["Jul/21","Aug/21","Sep/21","Oct/21","Nov/21","Dec/21"])) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This example raise the error

```py
 df[(df.col1=="pattern1") & (df.col2=="pattern2" | df.col2=="pattern3")]
```

But this works

```py
 df[(df.col1=="pattern1") & ((df.col2=="pattern2") | (df.col2=="pattern3"))]
```

You have to put parenthesis on all boolean